# Running "Active File" closing before I can see anything in VS Code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks, vscode-python

I just installed python onto my computer and I'm testing it with some simple code like `print("test")` and when I try to run the code through the `Terminal - Run Active File` it opens a command prompt window and closes it instantly. It only slowed down once enough for me to quickly read it but automatically closes.

How do I get the window to stop closes or is there another way to run python code in VS Code.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post what settings are in your `launch.json` file?

Answer (score 0):

In VSCode you can customize the settings for debugging Python code. For this you have to click on debugging on the left sidebar and then on the round icon in the upper left corner.

This will open the file `launch.json`. There you can customize the settings for debugging.

Here is what it should look like:

[image]

Now if you set `"console"` to `"none"`, VSCode uses the internal debugging console, while setting it to `"integratedTerminal"` uses the the terminal within VSCode and `"externalTerminal"` uses the default terminal of your OS.

---

After you have modified `launch.json` you can choose one of the debug configurations from the dropdown menu as shown below.

[image]

For further information you can read through the official documentation about [debugging Python](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) in VSCode.